# Sequelize attribute does not work

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When I made a Query is like below.

```
models.A.findAndCountAll(
  {
    include: [
      models: models.B,
      as: 'C',
      attribute: ['a']
    ],
    order
    offset
    limit  
  }
)
```

A hasOne B as 'C'
B belongsTo A

There are 'a', 'b', 'c' fields in B and I just want to retrieve 'a'.
So I add the attribute option.

But when I execute this query I get all the field defined in B.
It's really terrible when there are many fields in B.

Did I do something wrong?

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Please replace `attribute` with `attributes`

Comment: .....Thank you very much. Maybe I should be more careful...

Comment: Also `models` should be `model`. And it needs to define the attributes.

Answer (score 2):

The query syntax for Sequelize requires you to pass in either a `Model`, and array of `Model`s, or an array of object definitions (as, attributes, etc). You are using square brackets (`[]`) for an array but treating the value as an object, so the attribute definition isn't included. Use curly braces (`{}`) to define the `Model` attributes to include. The object key for the model should be `model`, not `models` as in your example, and you are missing commas for the last parameters.

```
models.A.findAndCountAll(
  {
    include: [ 
      {  // <-- brace here
        model: models.B, // "models" key should be "model"
        as: 'C',
        attributes: ['a']
      }, // <-- brace here
    ],
    order,
    offset,
    limit,
  }
);
```